# Output values in Pixel Blender (trace)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, pixel-bender

I'm absolutely new to Pixel Blender (started a couple of hours ago).

My client wants a classic folding effect for his app, I've shown him some example of folding effect via masks and he didn't like them, so I decide to dive in Pixel Blender to try to write him a custom shader.

Thx God I've found [this one](http://superflashbros.net/2010/06/28/a-real-page-turner/) and I'm modyfing it by playing with values. But how can I trace / print / echo values from Pixel Blender ToolKit? This would speed up a lot all the tests I'm doing.

[Here](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2009/02/27/pixelbender-development-tool/) i've found in the comments that it's not possible, is it true?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot directly trace values in Pixel Bender, but you can, for example, make a certain bitmap, then apply that filter with requested values and trace reultant bitmap's pixel values to find out what point corresponded the one selected.

For example, you make a 256x256 bitmap, with each point (x,y) having "x" red and "y" green component value. Then you apply that filter with selected values, and either display the result, or respond to clicks and trace underlying color's red and green values, which will give you the exact point on the source bitmap.